# Android Layout not showing

Tags: android, layout, oncreate

When my quiz app starts for the first time it needs to add questions to a database and a few other things and this takes a few seconds. I want to display a indeterminate progressbar whilst this occurs. Once the questions are added, the class calls finish() and moves on to the main screen. The problem is that the layout isn't drawn unless finish isn't called. I assume it doesn't draw the XML layout until after the oncreate and onstart are called. So how do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason, the UI isn't shown while you're filling your DB is probably that you're doing that in the UI-Thread - the main thread of your application. As the thread is busy filling your DB, there is no time to show the UI, animate the progress indicator or react to user actions.

Thus you should always run time-consuming tasks in a separate thread. See this excellent entry in the android devloper's blog about **painless threading** for more information and to do it right:

- http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Comment: Thank you. I really didn't realise all this (I'm still new to developing). The linked article was really interesting, is there a place I can look up how to implement Async whilst still accessing my database and sharedpreferences?

Comment: Figured out how to get it to work. You guys both said the same thing but you gave more information. Thanks :) Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), display progress dialog in its `onPreExecute` and dismiss in `onPostExecute` prepare your db in `doInBackground`.

You would have to handle device rotation unless you are using DialogFragment to display your dialog.

Comment: I see that I have to implement AsyncTask. I read the documentation, however I'm not sure how to use it with accessing and writing to a SQLite database. Any chance you could offer some insight?

Comment: @user1676486 You can put your sql or any other operations into doInBackground() as long as they do not touch the UI